# Storyboard loaded from code ignoring constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, constraints

I have a storyboard built view with constraints that looks great when loaded via IB. When I try to load the same view from code the view looks to be placed correctly in the view but all of my constraints are off and when edited I don't see the changes in the simulator.

This is the code I am using to load the view -

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Pop" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FreshPopViewController"];

    firstPopView = vc.view;
    vc.view = nil;

    //firstPopView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    //[firstPopView setFrame:self.view.frame];
    [firstPopView setFrame:self.view.bounds];

    UIButton *requestButton = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:101];

    [requestButton addTarget:self action:@selector(newRequestButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:firstPopView];
```

As you see in the code I have tried different methods for setting the frame but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Make sure the constraints are activated for the devices(size classes) you're expecting.

Comment: All constraints are set for any any. I'm developing only for the normal iPhone view. Would I need to change anything in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding a containing view between the VC's view and all of my objects. I didn't have to edit anything in code, just re-do the constraints to this new view in IB.